# $g_i \mid g_j \;\;\text{in}\;\; K[X] \implies g_i \mid g_j\;\; \text{in}\;\; k[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$ and let $f(x) = x^p - a \in k[x]$.
Then, $f' = px^{p-1}=0$ and since $k$ is perfect, it follows that $f$ is reducible over $k$.

So we can write $f = g_1g_2\cdots g_r$ with $g_i \in k[x]$ irreducible.

Let $K$ be a splitting field for $f$ over $k$ and $\alpha \in K$ a root of $f$.

We then get $(x-\alpha)^p = x^p - \alpha^p = x^p - a^p = f = g_1g_2\cdots g_r \implies g_i = (x-\alpha)^{a_i}$ in $K[x]$ for some $a_i$.

W.l.o.g. $\text{deg}\;g_i \leq \text{deg}\;g_j  \implies g_i \mid g_j \;\;\text{in}\;\; K[X]$

**Why does it then follow that $g_i \mid g_j\;\; \text{also in}\;\; k[X]$?**

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663283/if-a-polynomial-divides-another-in-a-polynomial-ring-will-the-division-also-occ

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Since $k$ is perfect, $a$ has a unique $p$-th root in $k$, call it $\beta$. The consequences are that $K=k$, and $f(x)=(x-\beta)^p$.